# Ember.js ember-data restadapter fail to load json

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

Cheers! 
I have ember-data store:

```
TravelClient.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({ bulkCommit: false, url: "http://someIP:somePORT"})
});
```

And router:

```
TravelClient.ToursRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return TravelClient.Tour.find();
  }
});
```

I recieve this JSON from remote server:

```
{
  "tours": [
    {
      "id": "5110e8b5a8fefe71e0000197",
      "title": "qui deserunt dolores",
      "description": "Id velit nihil.",
      "seats": 12,
      "options": [

      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": "5110e8b5a8fefe71e0000196",
          "url": "url"
        }
}
```

But when I try to `return TravelClient.Tour.find()` it fails with:

```
http://someIP:somePORT/tours 404 (Not Found)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://someIP:somePORT/tours. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

IT seems like RESTAdapter doesn't know, that it must receive JSON or what?

**UPDATE:**

In the application controller on the rails server-side:

```
def set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
end
```

But it's still :

```
OPTIONS http://someIP:somePORT/tours 404 (Not Found)
```

And it looks like RESTAdapter tries to load tours resource, not tours.json:

```
Request URL:http://someIP:somePORT/tours
```

**WORKING SOLUTION**

Extend RESTAdapter:

```
TravelClient.CUSTOMAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  bulkCommit: false, 
  url: "http://remote_server_address",    
  buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
    var s = this._super(record, suffix);
    return s + ".json";
  }
})
```

and respond to an OPTIONS request with right headers

Comment: the headers you set are returned with the `GET` request you need to return them with an `OPTIONS` request

Comment: Rack CORS gem did the trick, thanks. I think it's doing all that stuff with OPTIONS requests just "out of the box".

Comment: Heres the link for the next visitor https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors ftw

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `RESTAdapter` expects `JSON` that is not the problem but the page and the json are not on the same domain, this is a security issue. You can resolve this by using one of the two solutions named below.

You're running into the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you should either use `JSONP` or `CORS`. The quickest fix would probably be to tell ember-data that you want to use `JSONP`.

For `CORS` your server needs to respond to an `OPTIONS` request with the headers:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
- `Access-Control-Request-Method`

i'm no rails expert but you will probably need to do something with the gem `rack-cors` see [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/02/27/supporting-cross-domain-ajax-in-rails-using-jsonp-and-cors/) or [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-cors).

You could do that by overriding the `ajax` hook in the `RESTAdapter` like so:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        namespace: "data",
        url: "",
        ajax: function (url, type, hash) {
            hash.url = url;
            hash.type = type;
            hash.dataType = 'jsonp';
            hash.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
            hash.context = this;

            if (hash.data && type !== 'GET') {
                hash.data = JSON.stringify(hash.data);
            }

            jQuery.ajax(hash);
        },
    })
});
```

Comment: To use CORS I just need to add smth like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to server's response header?

Comment: yes see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS There are some other headers you can control more specifically what is allowed.

Comment: Rack CORS gem is just for more specific customization - not what I need at the moment, but thank you for attention.

Comment: You need to respond to a OPTIONS request with the headers somehow.

Comment: but my server responding to an OPTIONS request, I have right headers in response.

Comment: it isn't otherwise you wouldn't get a 404 :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple work around in Rails (that is working for me so far.) It is untidy as is, but can easily be tightened up with logic in the controllers.

In `routes.rb`:

```
match   ':path' => 'authentications#allow', constraints: {method: 'OPTIONS'}
```

Which simply returns status `OK` to any `OPTIONS` request.

```
def allow
  head :ok
end
```

And then in `application_controller.rb` set the Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) headers for every request:

```
before_filter :cors
def cors
  response.headers.merge! 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, PUT, GET, DELETE', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type'
end
```

Comment: But there was nothing wrong with my headers, just Rails was giving me back html, while I was needing json. So workaround just is saying to Rails directly that you want json - extend adapter's buildURL method. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use JSONP it's much easier to override the private `ajaxOptions` function instead of using `jQuery` and overriding the `ajax` method. Ember's pipeline includes the removal of the jQuery dependency. So do this instead:

`adapters/application.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajaxOptions: function(url, type, options) {
        var hash = this._super(url, type, options);
        hash.dataType = "jsonp";
        return hash;
    }
});
```

It would be create if the Ember core team could expose a public method to officially support this (instead of hacking a private api).

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/1.0.0-beta.15/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L915