# Ember-Data rev. 11 <-> Error: XML instead of JSON as content type

Tags: wcf, ember.js, ember-data

Why is ember requesting XML instead of JSON?

**XML Response according to firebug**:

XML-processing defect: No element found address: moz-nullprincipal:{664ded3f-7063-4f92-b404-3895f595c584} Row No. 1, Column 1: [my translation into English]

**Ember Data Request (Not Working)**

Request Header:

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Response Header:

Content-Type    application/xml; charset=utf-8

**Ajax Request (Working)**

Request Header:

Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Response Header:

application/json; charset=utf-8

**My store and Adapter**

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
revision: 11,

});


DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: '.../json/ember'
});
```

**My nested Model**

```
App.Line = DS.Model.extend({
    lineIdentifier: DS.attr('string'),  
    shifts: DS.hasMany('App.Shift'),
});


App.Shift = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    line: DS.belongsTo('App.Line'), 
});
```

**My WCF Interface**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/json/ember/lines"
        )]
    LinesArray LinesEmber();
```

**My JSON**

```
{
     "Line":[
            {"Shift":[{},{},{},{}],...},
            {"Shift":[{},{},{},{}],...}]
}
```

Well response would be fantastic, it's the last big coding step for my master thesis. :) Thanks in advance.

**[Update]**

Failed ember call: For me it's surprising, that ember requests xml... 
[image: Failed ember call]

Successful ajax call
[image: Successful ajax call]

Comment: You can override the jquery ajax function like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828478/ember-js-ember-data-restadapter-fail-to-load-json/14828656#14828656

Comment: @alberjan: I added cors, according do this [tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234599/cors-support-within-wcf-rest-services). After modifying "adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({...})" according to your link, ember doesn't fire the option requests any longer. Only my ajax call got fired. Any additional ideas? Your support is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Headers setting Authorization header stops data from loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755570/http-headers-setting-authorization-header-stops-data-from-loading)