# HTTP Headers setting Authorization header stops data from loading

Tags: jquery, ember.js, http-headers, cors, http-authentication

I'm using Ember.js, Ember Simple Auth plugin and jQuery to send an `Authorization` header cross domain using ajax. When the `Authorization` header is set:

```
jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + session.get('authToken'));
```

Then I get a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request to the REST URL which I then return back the following headers:

```
$headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://subdomain2.domain.com');
$headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
$headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Accept');
$headers->set('Access-Control-Max-Age', 10);
$headers->set('Content-Length', 0);
```

In Chrome Network monitor, this `OPTIONS` request returns successful. Then when the GET request comes after the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request, the `GET` request just hangs or at least says `(pending)` in network monitor:

[image]

If I refresh the page a couple of seconds later the page will show, but it just doesn't show immediately after the `OPTIONS` call.

When I play with the `Access-Control-Max-Age` header and increase the cache time, then I can refresh many times before it sends the `OPTIONS` call again which means the page will show just fine. It's only when the `OPTIONS` call comes with the `GET` immediately after does it hang.

When I load the url directly in the browser it displays the JSON data just fine. Even when I use the Chrome extension Postman and manually set the `Authorization` header the same as the jQuery request, it still loads the data just fine (although I don't think Postman simulates cross domain requests).

Any idea why the `GET` request remains pending and doesn't return any errors or headers?

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what the problem is here. Looks like you're running into sth. similar to this: [cross-origin 'Authorization'-header with jquery.ajax()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559947/cross-origin-authorization-header-with-jquery-ajax)

Also, did you change anything in the Ember.SimpleAuth code? Because by default it shouldn't include the token in cross domain requests for security reasons...

You might also want to look at this known problem in jQuery: [Sending credentials with cross-domain posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/) that also relates to sending the Authorization header cross-domain.

I'll look into how Ember.SimpleAuth could maybe help in this scenario.

Comment: It's odd because if I refresh it seems to work, so I do return the correct headers after the `OPTIONS` request. I didn't change the `SimpleAuth` code - I did notice the line `if (!jqXHR.crossDomain && !Ember.isEmpty(session.get('authToken'))) {` but the `jqXHR` object doesn't contain the `crossDomain` property...I actually found the cross domain property is in the `options` object. Possibly a bug or a difference in systems? I've temporarily solved the situation by changing the `REST` server to the same domain. I don't think it's a `SimpleAuth` issue, maybe a bug...i'm not sure.

Comment: I've also tried adding `jqXHR.withCredentials = true;` before it sends the `Authorization` header and this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did some investigation: in general Ember.SimpleAuth should work with CORS. I think what you're missing is the

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://subdomain2.domain.com
```

header in the response to the GET request. Also see the example in the Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. Every response must contain the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for checking. I definitely return this value as you can see from the question above `$headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://subdomain2.domain.com');` and it works when I refresh quickly so it's definitely not blocking the cross domain request. Maybe it's a bug in my system somewhere, i'll do some more poking around.

Comment: hm, looked like you only had the headers in the response for the OPTIONS request not the GET. Also do you see anything in the log?

Comment: Ah no had it for both GET and OPTIONS. If I didn't have it for GET none of the requests would work. Seems really odd.